# Problem about uniform convergence

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

> Prove that the series
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+x^2}$$
>   converges  uniformly and conditionally on $\mathbb{R}$.

I have difficulties about this calculus question of uniform convergence

Comment: For an intuitive look at it, for what value of $x$ does the sum take on it's largest value? If the highest value the sum can take on is finite, then what can you say about the rest of the x's. Note, this is more or less just a way to build intuition.

Answer (score 3):

Hint. For any real $x$, the sequence 
$$f_N(x):=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+x^2}$$
converges (conditionally) by the [Leibniz test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) to some $f(x)$.

In order to show  that $(f_N)_N$ converges to $f$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$, consider, the following inequality.

Let $N\geq M\geq 1$, and for $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
Since the sequence  $n\to 1/(n+x^2)$ decreases to zero, it follows that the alternating sum is bounded from above by the first term
\begin{align*}|f_{N}(x)-f_{M}(x)|&=\left|\sum_{n=M+1}^{N} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+x^2}\right|
\leq \frac{1}{M+1+x^2}\leq \frac{1}{M+1}.
\end{align*}
Hence, by taking the limit as $N\to \infty$, we obtain that for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$|f(x)-f_{M}(x)|\leq \frac{1}{M+1}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: i think you are trying to show that $f_N(x)$ is uniformaly cauchy on $\mathbb{R}$. if this is so, then i think we need to show that for arbitary $N,M$ instead of $2N,2M$??

Comment: @Eklavya Thanks for your comment. I edited my answer. Now it looks better, am I right?

Comment: yap thats right

Comment: Thank you very much, @RobertZ :) but could you explain further? I'm entry level to this subject

Comment: @Jay Take the limit for $N\to \infty$ and you are done!

Comment: *"it follows that the alternating sum is bounded from above by the first term"* - I don't understand this part. How can we conclude this while more positive terms are being added to the sum after the first term (together with the negative terms)?

Comment: @VIVID If $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ decreases to $0$ then
$$a_0-a_1+a_2-a_3+a_4+\dots=a_0-\underbrace{(a_1-a_2)}_{\geq 0}-\underbrace{(a_3-a_4)}_{\geq 0}+\dots\leq a_0$$

Comment: @RobertZ What a nice technique, thank you!

Comment: @VIVID You are welcome!